# Can a GitLab project be globally configured such that all code samples are syntax highlighted with a default the language?

Tags: gitlab, syntax-highlighting, sample

I have a (La)TeX project hosted on GitLab. For (almost) all the code samples inserted (in tickets, comments, PR, etc.) thanks to:

````
```
⟨(La)TeX code sample⟩
```
````

we need to specify the (`latex`) language, like this:

````
```latex
⟨(La)TeX code sample⟩
```
````

Is there a way to configure this (La)TeX project in order to not have to systematically specify the (`latex`) language, with the possibility, when needed, to specify a language other than the `latex`?